# on iOS, can apps import/export folder structures?

Tags: ios, file

in an iOS app, is it possible to share a whole folder, potentially containing sub folders, with another app? On the receiving side, is there a way to import such folder structure?

Or is file handling restricted to flat lists of files & individual files?

In an app I am working on, I want to process structured folders containing files & subfolders, with the folder tree intact - a user should be able to open a folder in my app. Not sure if that's possible, couldn't find an answer, so I guess not.

clarification:
implementing support for the share sheet, it's trivial to enable an app to open specific file types using UTIs. the app will simply show up in the system Share Sheet if a user in another app shares a supported file, and you just handle URLs in the app delegate. This works for multiple files, but is it possible to do it with entire directory structures? Individual files are copied into the target app's container, should be doable with folders as well, hopefully.

Comment: What do you mean "send"? Send how? What "other app" is supposed to know there's a folder hierarchy, how will it know, and where will this folder be?

Comment: such as using the share sheet - it's trivial to enable an app to open specific file types using UTIs - the app will then show up in the system Share sheet, and you just handle URLs in the app delegate. This works for multiple files, but is it possible to do it with directory structures? Individual files are copied into the target app's container, should be possible to do the same thing with folders...

Comment: Good answer, but I would suggest you say that specifically in the question.

Comment: sorry, long day, brain is fried tbh

Comment: if you own both apps (using the same Apple account), you can share data between apps using app groups. This enables you to write/read to/from disk, in a container that is accessible by both apps.